# Hide Div after showing 5sec

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve:

1. Hide Form Area after button click (DONE)
2. Show submit confirmation message on button click (DONE)
3. Hide Show submit confirmation message after showing it for 5 seconds
4. Show form area again

I'm stuck on point 3 & 4 and would appreciate any hints. I have tried the set time out function but without luck.I must be doing something wrong.

```
function hideDiv() {
               document.getElementById('FormArea').style.display = "none";
              }

function showDiv() {
              document.getElementById('submitarea').style.display = "block";
         }


setTimeout(function() {
    $('#submitarea').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here? The timeout should work fine, but not if you're changing the display property to `none` before fading out, then there's nothing to fade out. Also, the timeout is not inside any of the functions?

Comment: create fiddler if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
<input onclick="hidediv(); showdiv(); reshow();">

function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('FormArea').style.display = "none";
}

function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('submitarea').style.display = "block";
}

function reshow(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#submitarea').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#FormArea').fadeIn('fast');
    }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
}
```